# Meaning of “BNL1” and “BNL2” on Schengen visa sticker?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

I have got two Schengen business visas in 2014 and 2015 and I traveled through Schengen area. Now I have got  my 3rd business visa. The question I want to ask is that on previous two visa stickers there is written BNL2 and this time there is written BNL1. What do they mean?

Answer (score 10):

[From this Home Affairs document explaining the codes](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/doc_centre/borders/docs/Annex%2022_COMMENTS%20SECTION_14.2.2011_EN.pdf):

- **BNL 1   :    visa issued following authorisation by the central authorities.**
- **BNL 2   :    visa issued ex officio.**
- BNL 3   +  name of the border point of entry and/or the date of entry: this code will only be 
  indicated for security reasons in exceptional cases.
- BNL 4   :    visa issued in the framework of
  representation following consultation of the 
  represented State.
- BNL 5   +  x days: 
   the visa holder must report 
  to the police within "x days".
- BNL 8   :    visa issued for "medical treatment". 
   If appropriate, the name of the hospita
  l in question can be added to this code.
- BNL 9   :    NO INSURANCE REQUIRED.
- BNL 10 :    visa issued for "study purposes".
- BNL 11 :    visa issued for the 
  purpose of "family reunification".
- BNL 12 :    visa issued fo
  r "professional purposes".
- BNL 13 :    visa issued for "business purposes".
- BNL 14 :    visa issued with a view to "adoption".
- BNL 15 :    C visas issued to aliens posted to an embassy, consulate, representation or international organisation, and to members of their family, spouse, children and domestic staff living in their household and dependent on them.
- BNL 16 :    visa issued for "partnership"
- BNL 17 :    visa issued for "marriage"
- BNL18:     + name of accompanying parent or guardian: for visas issued to minors who travel accompanied.
- BNL19:     + name of host: for visas issued to minors who travel unaccompanied.

As you can see, the BNL1/2 just indicate how it was issued.